# Display LaTeX code in a document

Tags: errors

I have a LaTeX document in which I want to display in the main document the way a LaTeX function is used, for example:

> \documentclass{name} is bla bla bla

the thing is that LaTeX always recognises `\documentclass` as a function, therefore throwing an error.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered encasing the string `\documentclass{name}` in a `\verb+...+` statement? (The `+` character should be chosen in a way that ensures that it's not also used in the verbatim string itself.) Alternatively -- and this may be especially relevant if you do *not* want to render the string using a monospaced font -- you could write `\textbackslash$\{$name$\}$` to preserve both the backslash and the curly braces.

Comment: @Mico why the math mode around `\{` and `\}`?

Comment: Thank you very much! The \verb+..+ solution does the job perfectly

Comment: @Mico please either post an answer, or vote to close as a duplicate (must be one somewhere)

Comment: @cmhughes - done!

Comment: @cgnieder - The use of the inline math mode delimiters is indeed unnecessary!

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two methods for typesetting `\documentclass{name}` without LaTeX being tripped up by the three "special" characters in the string, viz., `\`, `{`, and `}`:

- The "verbatim" method will result in the string being typeset using a "monospaced" font -- which is probably what you want.
- You could "escape" the special characters directly, resulting in the string being typeset using the default text font (probably a serif font).

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}

  % verbatim method - the delimiter character (here: +)
  %   mustn't appear in the string being rendered in 
  %   verbatim mode
  \verb+\documentclass{name}+ 

  % or, use macros to "escape" the backslash and curly braces
  \textbackslash documentclass\{name\}

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: As an addition: the font used by `\verb` and the `verbatim` environment is stored in `\verbatim@font` and defaults to `\normalfont\ttfamily`. It can simply be redefined to get another verbatim formatting.